# How can we define a potential for a moving charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge, potential, vector-fields

Say a charge is moving in space. Ignoring relativistic effects, how can we define a scalar potential for its electric field ?

My thoughts are that we can define the potential in exactly the same way as we did in electrostatics only that here our scalar potential will be time dependent. That is we go to some time instant, and at that instant compute the potential as we do in electrostatics, and keep on doing this for all time, hence resulting in a scalar time-dependent potential.

Comment: Are you just asking if we can define it? Or are you wanting more information pertaining to this? I suggest editing the question to be clearer here (unless you really are just looking for a "yes or no" answer).

Comment: Thank you, I've edited it.

Comment: Welcome to electrodynamics.

Comment: @Frobenius, thank you. It has throughly welcomed me by confusing me.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My thoughts are that we can define the potential in exactly the same way as we did in electrostatics only that here our scalar potential will be time dependent.

You cannot describe the electromagnetic field of a moving charge as the gradient of a potential. If you could, the curl of the electric field would be zero, which would imply that the time derivative of the magnetic field would be zero. This is clearly false.

Describing the field of a moving charge requires a scalar potential $\varphi$ *and* a vector potential $\mathbf{A}$. The two potentials determine the two fields as follows:

$$\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\varphi-\frac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial t},$$

$$\mathbf{B}=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}.$$

Together $\varphi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ make up the four components of the “four-potential” $A^\mu$, a Lorentz four-vector. So although $\varphi$ is a scalar under rotations, it is just one component of a four-vector under a Lorentz boost.

The scalar and vector potentials for an arbitrarily-moving point charge are known as the [Liénard-Wiechert potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) and are reasonably simple expressions.

Comment: Thank you G. Smith. So if I've a moving charge and at a particular Instant it's at a point say $r$ then its electric field  at that instant will be different than a stationary charged at the same point ?

Comment: @YasirSadiq Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Oh wow, that's surprising!.

Comment: If we have a varying current in a resistor that means a time varying electric field in it which is caused by charges moving around but still we define a scalar potential difference $V$ across a resistor?

Comment: Please don’t ask new questions in comments. Your question had nothing to do with resistors.

Comment: I apologize. You might want to have a look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588388/how-is-potential-difference-defined-across-a-resistor-with-time-varying-current?noredirect=1#comment1324908_588388

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the usual way. The charge density would just be time-dependent.
See: [Four-Potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential)

Comment: Thank you, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

We can get potential from charge distribution $\rho$ in the following usual way:
$$\phi(\textbf{r},t)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int d^3r’~ \frac{\rho\left(\textbf{r}’,t-\tau\right)}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}’|}$$
where $\tau = (\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}’)/c$ accounts for the time delay due to finite propagation speed of the fields. For more details you can look up the Wikipedia page on [retarded potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_potential).

So now for the case with a charge $q$ moving with a velocity $\textbf{v}$ starting from origin, the charge distribution is given by:
$$\rho(\textbf{r}’,t)=q\delta\left(\textbf{r}-\textbf{v}t\right)$$

However, remember that now we have a time varying charge distribution. This means to describe the electric field, you’ll need to know the vector potential as well.

For further details on this, look up the Wikipedia page for [Liénard–Wiechert potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential).

Comment: Thank you but as G. Smith said" You cannot describe the electromagnetic field of a moving charge as the gradient of a potential. If you could, the curl of the electric field would be zero, which would imply that the time derivative of the magnetic field would be zero." how do you resolve it?

Comment: “This means to describe the electric field, you’ll need to know the vector potential as well.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the potential defined in the way you described is so-called Coulomb potential, or electric potential in "Coulomb gauge":

$$
\varphi(\mathbf x,t ) = K \int_{whole~space} \frac{\rho(\mathbf x',t)}{|\mathbf x-\mathbf x'|} \,d^3\mathbf x '.
$$

Here, potential at some time $t$ depends on charge distribution at the same exact time $t$.

There is infinity of other different ways to define electric potential. One of the more interesting ones is the retarded solution to the "inhomogeneous wave equation"

$$
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \varphi}{\partial^2 t} - \Delta \varphi = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$
which @Superfast Jellyfish described. This potential at any position $\mathbf x$ and time $t$ is function of charge distribution at all positions $\mathbf x'$ at various times $t'\leq t$, where $t' =  t-\frac{|\mathbf x-\mathbf x'|}{c}$.

Comment: Thank you but the potential you defined has the problem that it violates Maxwell equation as G. Smith said "You cannot describe the electromagnetic field of a moving charge as the gradient of a potential. If you could, the curl of the electric field would be zero, which would imply that the time derivative of the magnetic field would be zero."

Comment: The $\rho$ on the left side of your first equation should be $\varphi$.

Comment: @G.Smith right, fixed.

Comment: @YasirSadiq no it does not violate Maxwell's equations. I did not claim this potential fully describes electric field.

Comment: Oh sorry I felt like it meant that but anyways thank you for your time. :)