# How is potential difference defined across a resistor with time varying current

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, vector-fields

From this discussion [How can we define a potential for a moving charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588228/how-can-we-define-a-potential-for-a-moving-charge/588268#588268) we know that we cannot define a  scalar potential (as in electrostatics) in the case of moving charges as described by G. Smith:

> You cannot describe the electromagnetic field of a moving charge as the gradient of a potential. If you could, the curl of the electric field would be zero, which would imply that the time derivative of the magnetic field would be zero. This is clearly false

How then can we define a potential difference across  a resistor with time varying current?

Comment: The simple answer is to define it as what your oscilloscope measures across the given circuit element.

Comment: Say we are analysing a circuit theoretically, then?

Comment: One thing to consider is that in dc and reasonably low frequency ac circuits the charges are moving very very slowly. Once into the microwave region one does move towards a full wave picture of signal propagation.

Comment: Anyways, the potential difference is not due to the field of the free charges but to the power supply. So the premise of the question is flawed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How then can we define a potential difference across a resistor with time varying current?

Basically we just assume that we can.

Circuit theory is an approximation to Maxwell’s equations which relies on three assumptions:

1. the distances are small enough and the time scales large enough that we can treat electromagnetic effects as instantaneous rather than propagating at c.
2. there is no net charge on any component.
3. there is no magnetic flux outside of any component.

With those three assumptions the vector potential from Maxwell’s equations becomes zero and only the scalar potential remains. And also the Coulomb gauge can be used (up to a simple additive constant) for that potential. While the statement by G. Smith is absolutely correct, the errors introduced by simply using the Coulomb potential anyway go to zero as deviations from these assumptions go to zero. Thus circuit theory is a well defined approximation to Maxwell’s equations and in that approximation the potential difference across a resistor is well defined.

Comment: After having studied electrical engineering, I find half of the things I learned cue up the image of Captain Barbarosa from Pirates of the Caribbean: "They're more like guidelines."

Comment: @Cort Ammon that is hilarious. I am trying to figure out how I can incorporate that into my answer

Comment: @ Dale, thank you. Can you please refer a source that discusses this exactly.

Comment: @Yasir Sadiq Yes, I got it from Electric Circuits by Nilsson and Riedel in chapter 1. I am sure other similar texts will discuss this topic also.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)